# Can you identify this helicopter seen near Boscombe Down?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-identification

[image: Photo of dark green helicopter]

Please can you identify this helicopter seen near [Boscombe Down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOD_Boscombe_Down) (near Amesbury, Wiltshire, England) in January 2024?

Comment: Where is Boscombe Down?

Comment: @breversa https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOD_Boscombe_Down

Comment: And to save people the trouble of following links, we could also just say that Boscombe Down is near Amesbury, Wiltshire, England.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AH-64D Block I Apache Longbow. Produced by Westland on license from Boeing.
UK Army Air Corps painting and mods visible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to those who helped. I found navigating the site less than straightforward.

Comment: A later edit to the earlier answer IDed it as an AH-64E, based on the datalink antennas.  Are you still convinced this is an AH-64D Block I, and if so, what's your reasoning?

Answer (score 60):

[Apache Longbow](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/apache-longbow) headed a slightly different direction.

[image]

Specific model is AH-64E, indicated by the presence of [datalink antennas](https://www.key.aero/article/all-you-need-know-about-british-armys-new-ah-64e-apache-gunships) (OP's photo) on the stub wings.

[image]

Comment: That was so simple, it doesn't even deserve an upvote - just kidding!

Comment: +1 for the identical but not identical photo and facetious description.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that I've seen these elsewhere on the South Coast (specifically, towards the Eastern end of the South Downs) so they're not really a rarity.